# squid log format ending with a '\n'

Tags: squid

I need to terminate a squid log with a newline character.

I can not figure out reading the http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/

Has anyone does this? If so, how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new line is included by default. No need for any change